# Access a YouTube Clip's start and end point

Tags: youtube

The URL's for YouTube Clips appear to follow no logic other than they have:
`https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx` + 32 characters.

For example, for a 15 second clip starting at the beginning of: 
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiXD4xVJM5Y&ab_channel=JamieDupuis`

The link is: 
`https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs`

There is nothing in the URL that would suggest it starts at 0 seconds, last 15 seconds or comes from video ID NiXD4xVJM5Y.

From the HTML I was able to find:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<ytd-app>
...
<div#content.style-scope.ytd-app>
...
<ytd-page-manager#page-manager.style-scope.ytd-app>
...
<ytd-watch-flexy class="style-scope ytd-page-manager hide-skeleton" video-id="NiXD4xVJM5Y"...>
```

But I cannot find the start point, end point, and/or duration.

Ideally, I would use a Python package to read the HTML, get the start and end point or get the start point and determine the end point by adding the duration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in the source code there are the three variables I am looking for:

- videoId
- startTimeMs
- endTimeMs

No need for the YouTube API, just selenium to access this.